# Proper way to "group" PHP classes

Tags: php, object

Assuming these two classes,
with completely different properties and methods.

```
class Operation {
    private $amount;
    private $datetime;
}

class BankAccount {
    private $owner;
    private $number;
}
```

Both belong to the "Budget" feature.
What is the correct way to link these classes together?

It would make more sense to call them with something like that:

```
Budget.Operation()
Budget.BankAccount()
```

I think it wouldn't make sense to use "extends" because "Budget" is not a thing.

I hope this question has not already been asked, but I havent found good keywords..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into namespaces - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

It can be as simple as declaring your namespace:

```
namespace Budget

class Operation {

}

class BankAccount {

}
```

You could access them like this:

```
use \Budget\BankAccount
```

or

```
$account = new \Budget\BankAccount();
```